# INT type in SQL max value calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, bit

I am currently learning SQL.

When looking at the INT, I came to the understanding that an INT type is 4 bytes long, which translates to 8 bits each byte, leading to each INT being 32 bits.

However, for INT it is said that the max value for unsigned types is (2^32)-1 where the -1 is accounting for 0 value. I understand that the 32 comes from the fact that each int is 32 bits.

My question is where does the 2 come from in the calculation?

My intuition is telling me that each bit will have some sort of measure valued at 2.

Comment: Well, there are 10 kinds of people...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers use binary system for storing values. Let's try analogy between binary and decimal system:

Consider 10-based (decimal) system. If You have number with 32 decimal places, every place having value 0-9, You have 10^32 possible values (obviously enough; we use this system on daily basis).

Now consider 2-based system, which is the one used by computers (for practical reasons - two states are easiest to distinguish and wiring logic is simplest). Every place (bit) has value 0-1, so there are 2^32 possible values.

Comment: I understand. The calculation seems to imply that there are 32 positions with 2 possible choices for each leading to 4,294,967,296 as the number of possible choices. But how exactly does this translate to this being the maximum value of int being 4,294,967,295 after accounting for zero. Is this because if we choose 1 for all 32 positions and convert from binary to decimal we get 4,294,967,295?

Answer (score 1):

`int` is actually a signed value in SQL.  The range is from `-2^31` through `2^31 - 1`, which is `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.  There are exactly `2^32` possible values in tis range.  Note that it includes `0`.

An unsigned integer would range from  `0` to `2^32-1`, that is up to `4,294,967,295`.  The `- 1`s are because `0` is included in the range, so the counting starts at `0` rather than `1`.

The range of possible values is easily seen at with fewer bits.  For instance, 3 bits can represent the values from -4 to 3:

```
Bits    Unisgned     Signed
000        0            0
001        1            1
010        2            2
011        3            3
100        4           -4
101        5           -3
110        6           -2
111        7           -1
```

Comment: This was helpful thank you. I had suspicion that this was due to the choice between 0 and 1. However given my lack of knowledge in binary had failed to realize how the  4,294,967,295 possible combinations for the 32 positions also translated to this being the largest value. Your chart was helpful.